# SSD and HDD have window 7 recovery partition. Can I delete one to make room for ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, data-recovery

I'm trying to install ubuntu right now, and I've run into a problem. I have Windows 7 installed on my SSD, and I want to install ubuntu on my HDD, but I already have three partitions on my HDD. The partitions are two Recovery Partitions and one data partition. What I don't understand is why my data drive(the HDD) has recovery partitions for Windows 7? The same recovery partitions(or atleast I think they are the same. Same sizes, same names, same order) are on the SSD with the Windows 7 install. Can I safely delete the recovery partitions on the HDD?

My other option, I think, is to put the boot partition for ubuntu on the SSD where I only have three partitions. Then I can put the other three logical partitions for ubuntu in an extended partition on the HDD. Can I do that, put the boot partition on one drive and the other partitions on another?

Here is a picture of the partitions and I have circled the one I would like to delete to make room. 
[image: http://imgur.com/XOpJQ]

Comment: You seem to have 195GB free on disk 0. Why not use them ?

Comment: I agree, rather than messing with all that, just add an extended partition in that 195GB of free space and install Ubuntu there (so you have another partition for swap space). Also, by doing that you don't risk breaking things on the Windows side.

Comment: No no. The thing is that I need to make at least two partitions for the install. One primary and then I can put all the other logicals inside an extended partition. 

Anyways, I tested those strange duplicate recovery and boot partitions that were on the HDD by simply disconnecting the HDD and booting from the SSD only. Everything ran fine, Windows functioning, so I reconnected the HDD and deleted both that recovery and boot partition. Turned out fine. I think that they were just left over partitions from the last OS install on that hard drive. I think I just forgot to delete them before.

Comment: Sounds more like a Windows question to me than an Ubuntu question, as this is about whether or not removing those partitions would fry Windows.

Answer (score 0):

When you did the initial install you disconnected the HDD drive and did a clean install on the SSD is this correct?  The reason I asked is that I want to do essentially the same thing.

Do you program files operate correctly now?  Or did you have to move the data files to the SSD to get them to work.

I do agree with what you said initially is that the new install of Windows 7 actually created your new recovery files on the SSD like any new install.

To address the part about ubuntu OS, you can set up a dual boot partion if you have the acronis tools.  According to the new software update you can install as many operating systems as you would like to put on your partition.

I have used it to clone a whole disk to disk copy and it worked great.  But you will have to purchase Acronis 'Disk Director to do any major stuff but its worth it.

I hope that helped with your question.  I saw your article and it was of great interest to me being I am in the process of making similar changes to my system setups.

David

Comment: Windows surely will *boot* fine without recovery partitions. Question is wether they will be able to be *recovered* on error. But that's your decision of course.